# How to use a link API to post Data in Tastypie framework

Tags: django, api, rest, post, tastypie

Is there anyone here can teach me how to POST data through a link like:
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/?format=json&action=POST&username=someone&password=something
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Tastypie has a great documentation, you might want to read up on before POSTing to an API resource, a good starting point would be:

- https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interacting.html#creating-a-new-resource-post or
- https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html